# Correctly implementing a try/catch statement with regards to integer ArrayLists

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm writing a Java application which allows the user to enter a number of integer values and insert them into an ArrayList. The user should be asked after each item is entered, whether to continue entering data or to exit the application.

As well as that I have to enter a double value to see the type of exception thrown. Once identified, to write a Try/Catch statement which deals with the specific exception and allows the user to continue entering data (rather than having the application crash).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {
      System.out.println("please enter an integer: ");
      integer.add(input.next());
```

So far, I have creating the ArrayList and prompting the user for input done, now I'm having trouble with continuing to ask the user for input or asking them to stop the process (how do I do this?)

Also how do I write the try/catch block part? I understand that the 'try' part must contain statements that may cause an exception. So how can I write something like:

```
try {
  if input = double
  System.out.print("This is an error")?
}

catch(inputMismatchexception e){
....
}
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions for flow-control. There are better ways. BTW, your ArrayList is called "myArrayList", not "integer" ... If this is your real code, I doubt it compiles.

Comment: It won't compile, Signature of catch statement is incorrect too.

Comment: "The user should be asked **after each item is entered**, whether to continue entering data or to exit the application." - You may want to reconsider this. Imagine you have to enter all integers from 0 - 346 and you can't just type away, instead you have to press "Y" every single time ...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
try{
    myArrayList.add(input.nextInt());
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
}
 catch(NoSuchElementException e1){
}
  catch(IllegalStateException e2){
}
```

This will throw an InputMismatchError if the input is not an Integer, thus covering your Double input case.

After this, just prompt the user to confirm if they want to continue (something similar to what Ravi wrote in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble with continuing to ask the user for input or asking
>   them to stop the process

Inside your while loop

```
System.out.println("Do you want to continue  ?? (Y/N) ");
String str = input.next();
if(str.equals("N")
{
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.next()` always give you a string, so what you need to do is using `Integer.parseInt(input)` and check for `NumberFormatException`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("please enter an integer: ");
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            myArrayList.add(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO whatever you want to do here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going down a **wrong** path: you intend to use *exceptions* to *control* the *flow* of your program.

That is possible; but not regarded "good practice" in java.

As the name says, exceptions are for **exceptional** (aka error) scenarios. But the user wanting to stop the program - that is not an exceptional thing; that should be a **core** part of your logic!

In that sense: simply use your Scanner object to ask the user for string. And before turning those strings into numbers; you could check if the string is empty for example. Or if the string is equalIgnoreCase() to "quit". Allowing the user to stop the program by just hitting "enter", or by typing "quit".

For the record: you could also use exceptions; just going for Integer.parseInt("any string that is not a int number") will throw a NumberFormatException.

But as said: catching those and assuming the user did that on purpose to the end the loop is a **bad** idea. What if the user didn't pay attention; made a typo and didn't want to stop?! Wouldn't it be better if you told him "you didnt enter a valid number, try again"?